# How does one deal with sentences starting with a connective?

Tags: syntax-trees, conjunctions

While drawing syntax trees for *spoken language* and not ideal languages, how does one handle conjunctions and other particles appearing initially in sentences like:

*And* that is that. (After a long story)

*Also*, you must not forget to go to the practice today!

Comment: No differently to any other element. "And" would have the function label 'marker' and the category label 'coordinator' (your conjunction). "Also" is not a conjunction, but an adverb functioning as an adjunct. It serves as a connective denoting addition.

Comment: edits duly made, but shouldn't a conjunction take two arguments (at least in English)

Comment: Only a transitive conjunction.

Comment: o_O i have to read up!